# Identify this astronaut and shuttle mission

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, identify-this-object

After about `02:00` in the Kinematic video [SpaceX Delivers Critical Docking Adapter for NASA to the ISS](https://youtu.be/OHouzko8wr4?t=121) the astronaut says:

> You know the Space Shuttle’s been with us, it’s been the heart and soul of the human spaceflight program for about 30 years and you know, it’s a little sad to see it go away, but hopefully in the not too distant future you’re going to see a heavy lift vehicle manufactured by our commercial partners designed by NASA in partnership, and we’re going to go back to the Moon; back to Mars.
>
> So the future is very bright.

Is it possible to identify the astronaut and the shuttle mission?

Comment: same folks who made [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekWOS818g2w) discussed further in [Puzzler: Is this a Sputnik?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19706/12102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Chris Ferguson](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/ferguson_christopher.pdf), commander of STS-135 (which is the mission) and now manager of the Boeing CST-100 program, and slated to command its first mission.

still from video

[image]

crew portrait

[image]

in CST-100 suit

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought that what he said there was interesting and added it to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34832/12102) as well.